# adding a Div to html code got from remote site

Tags: php

6 hours of research and i can't figure this out as i am in learning phase, so i decided to ask someone here at this helpful community

I have remote page like remotesite.com/page1.html and we use the function file_get_contents to get its source, then we use DOMDocument to edit this source before printing it to our page

```
$url = "remotesite.com/page1.html";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
//here we do some edits to remove or add contents
```

I want to add the Div below to the to html code  got from remote site before printing it:

```
<div style="float: right; padding-right: 2px;"><a class="open_event_tab" target="_blank" href="some-hard-coded-text-here_'+content+'_title_'+lshtitle+'_event_'+id+'.html" >open event</a></div>
```

after my search i managed to write the function to create the div, here is my code

```
function createDivNode($doc) {
$divNode = $doc->createElement('div');
$divNode->setAttribute('style', 'float: right; padding-right: 2px;');
$aNode = $doc->createElement('a', 'openEvent');
$aNode->setAttribute('class', 'open_event_tab');
$aNode->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
$aNode->setAttribute('href', 'some-hard-coded-text-here_'+content+'_title_'+lshtitle+'_event_'+id+'.html');
$divNode->appendChild($aNode);
return $divNode;
```

but now i have two problems :

1- he soft coded part ( `'+content+'_title_'+lshtitle+'_event_'+id+'`) of the href is not working.

2- i dont know to add the div to position i want

i want to loop through the html source code got from the remote site to get every td that look like the one below and add the div just before closing the td tag

```
  <td colspan="2">
     <b>Video </b> 
     <span class="section">Sports</span><b>: </b> 
     <span id="category466" class="category">Motor Sports</span>

    //here i want to add my div
</td>
```

Comment: There is probably no need to create a dom element (createDivNode) - just create the html statement as a string. The $aNode->setAttribute('href', 'some-hard-coded-text-here_'+content+'_title_'+lshtitle+'_event_'+id+'.html'); is trying to set multiple attributes, href, title and onclick. You need to create them separately.

Comment: @jeff can you elaborate abit more

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1. looks like you miss `$` in variable names and also concatenation in PHP is done with `.` not `+` :

```
$aNode->setAttribute('href', 'some-hard-coded-text-here_' . $content . '_title_' . $lshtitle . '_event_' . $id . '.html');
```

Ad 2. For that one you can construct some [xpath query](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) that will match your node(s) and then just `$node->appendChild($divNode)` to put it in.

Comment: yes the $ variables names are missing thats because they was written in jquery and i dont know how to write them in php here them in jquery http://pastebin.com/L5cqWhDP can you help me define them in php